# Why .SaveAs rtf destroy styles in document (Word 2016)

Tags: vba, ms-word, rtf

I have a document (European jurisprudence) in the form of a DOCX file. When I save it to RTF, after re-opening it has different numbering styles. Why?

My workflow:

1. Open the file
2. Macro SaveAsRtfTest - everything looks ok
3. Close file
4. Reopen the RTF file - not ok

My simple macro:

```vb
Private Sub SaveAsRtfTest()
  Dim fileName1 As String
  fileName1 = Replace(ActiveDocument.fullName, ".docx", ".rtf", , , vbTextCompare)
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=fileName1, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End Sub
```

But when I save manually there is the same issue.

Very important! Numbering is visible only after closing and opening the RTF file.

[image: screen]

Files (docx and rtf):
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnanHEI101rbhf8vgkipTUNwvXUQ4w

edit____

I've compared ActiveDocument.Range.xml content.

This is the portion shown on the screenshot from the RTF file:

```xml
<w:p wsp:rsidR="0026237B" wsp:rsidRPr="004F6791" wsp:rsidRDefault="0026237B" wsp:rsidP="0026237B">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ECHRHeading1"/>
        <w:listPr>
            <wx:t wx:val="Artykuł I."/>
            <wx:font wx:val="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:listPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="004F6791">
        <w:t>I.  THE CIRCUMSTANCES OF THE CASE</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

as compared to DOCX:

```xml
<w:p wsp:rsidR="00A32B8B" wsp:rsidRPr="004F6791" wsp:rsidRDefault="00A32B8B" wsp:rsidP="00A32B8B">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ECHRHeading1"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="004F6791">
        <w:t>I.  THE CIRCUMSTANCES OF THE CASE</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: I'm using Word 2016 on Office 365 64 bit.  When I open the documents there is no difference between them.

Comment: Did you check paragraph from screen? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes.  I specifically checked the paragraphs you showed in screen.

Comment: Thanks, but its very strange for me. Before save I have 0 when checking numbered items (Debug.Print ActiveDocument.CountNumberedItems) and after reopen ==15 (for rtf file). As I said - thanks.

Comment: Since this is also happening when you save manually you might have better luck tracking this down in an end-user venue, rather than here on Stack Overflow. It's almost certainly an issue with the RTF converter or the styles or your specific environment and is not related to macro code. People who work more in the end-user area are more likely to have encountered this kind of thing...

Comment: I know and understand. But often after my question users had said: "show your code", even that wasn't necessary.
I asked here beacuse prehaps someone had the same problem. 
Because Freeflow didn't see difference between files that have to be enviroment+styles+rtf converter issue. Thanks.

Comment: So in DOCX you have a normal paragraph that looks like a list entry, but actually is not. When saving to RTF it gets converted to an actual list. Probably has to do something with automatic document formatting, you can try looking in the Word settings (your OneDrive link does not work, keeps displaying "Something went wrong, please try to refresh the page").

Comment: This looks like a Word bug to me. The problem is that in RTF the style `Ju_H_I_Roman (ECHR_Heading_1)` is based on the hidden style `Heading 1`, and that hidden style *effectively* has an additional "Numbering" rule (which is displayed in its style summary), but when you go to edit the numbering rules for that style, it's not there ("None" is selected). A workaround is to "Modify" the `Heading 1` in the style editor in the RTF file, and in its "Numbering" settings just click "Ok" to extra-confirm the "None" that appears to be already selected there.

Comment: @GSerg - Thank you. this line of code solve my problem:
`ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).LinkToListTemplate ListTemplate:=Nothing`
But it was possible with your solution.

Comment: **edit** haha, after re-open saved rtf still error in style...

Comment: **edit once again** I've to use `ECHR_Heading_1` instead of `wdStyleHeading1` enumeration in my piece of code.. and works!